# How to use DB connection parameters in Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I'm trying to read files from S3 bucket and load them to RDS DB.
I have used AWS Glue Studio and configured a job to run a python script for this load.
I have also established a connection between Glue and RDS and added this connection in Job Details.

However, I had to define connection parameters again in the python script to establish connection to RDS like below.

```
conn = pg8000.connect(host,dbname,user,password);
cur = conn.cursor();
```

The job is running perfectly fine but I'm wondering is there a way to use the connection given in the Job details instead of hardcoding them in the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a successful established Glue connection, you don't have to reconnect again in your python script with `connect` function.

You can simply use `DynamicFrameReader` class from the glue library to retrieve the data from your database as follows:

```
datasource = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database=<database_name>, table_name=<table_name>, transformation_ctx="datasource"
```

It returns a dynamicFrame which can be converted in dataframe as well.

You can read more about that : [DynamicFrameReader](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader-from_catalog)

Comment: As I am also performing sql operations using this script, I am using a cursor object as explained. I'm not really sure DynamicFrameReader/DynamicFrameWriter is going to be helpful. Thanks for the answer, appreciate it

Comment: It doesn't seem to offer the Glue connection support with pg8000 library.